# What kinds of explosive environment objects are there and what are their attributes?

Tags: xcom-2

So there are several kinds of explosive objects. Some can be fired at directly and have a specific amount of health (like gas tanks), while cars and trucks can only be damaged indirectly by other area damage effects or missed shots.

I would like to gather some information about the different types of objects, like:

- amount of health (HP)
- explosive damage (Dmg)
- explosive radius/range (ExpRad)
- ...

1) Does anyone have a detailed overview of the volatile container/tanks etc?

- Gas tanks (HP=3, Dmg=3-6(?), Size=1x2, ExpRad=3(?))
- Train cargo tanks (HP=7, Dmg=?, Size=2x2(?), ExpRad=1(?))
- Gas stations (HP=3, Dmg=?-7(?), Size=1x2, ExpRad=1(?))
- Alien container (HP=3, Dmg=?, Size=1x1, ExpRad=1(?))
- ...

2) Do mission objectives like communication relays do area damage when destroyed?

3) Do vehicles have a specific (hidden) amount of health? How is damage resistance different between different type of vehicles?

- Cars
- Trucks
- Trikes
- ...

Any insights are welcome.

Comment: Cars and truck can also be damaged by weapons, not only explosives. Oftentimes you have to reposition because the car you used for cover was hit and will explode the following turn. It's a shame you can't target them normally, because it is possible to make them explode right away if hit with normal weaponry multiple times. I have had that three-wheeled thing explode, killing two Advent Troopers who used it as cover, when I missed them twice so that both misses hit the vehicle. You can actually use the Grenadier ability Demolition to do this intentionally.

Comment: @Padishar: You are of course correct about the "indirect" damage, I made an edit to point that out.

Comment: related (subquestion, actually): http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/255050/108003